# Add a Custom Column to the Members List and All Users Admin Pages in pmpro plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm new in wordpress plugin development i need halp to Add a Custom Column to the Members List and All Users Admin Pages in paid membership pro plugin

Answer (score 0):

Paid Membership pro provide following filter to add custom columns into members list :

1. pmpro_manage_memberslist_columns : use to add custom column.
2. pmpro_manage_memberslist_custom_column : use to add column data.

For Example :

```
public function my_memberslist_columns( $columns )    {
    $columns['company_name']     = 'company name';
    $columns['joined_date'] = 'Joined Date';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'pmpro_manage_memberslist_columns', 'my_memberslist_columns');

public function my_cols_body( $colname, $user_id ) {
    if ( 'company_name' === $colname ) {
        echo "xyz pvt ltd";
    }
    if ( 'joined_date' === $colname ) {
        echo "2020-12-01";
    }
}
add_filter( 'pmpro_manage_memberslist_custom_column', 'my_cols_body', 10, 2 );
```